# nightwatch runs single test twice

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

When running nightwatch on a single testsuite, it starts the suite twice in parallel, resulting in errors. How can I make sure it just runs once?

This is my output:

```
> nightwatch --test tests/een.js --env default
Starting selenium server... started - PID:  2936

[Een] Test Suite
================

Running:  step one - start game
started - PID:  2936

[Een] Test Suite
================

Running:  step one - start game
No assertions ran.


Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:556:19)

Connection refused! Is selenium server started?
```

The test itself is almost empty:

```
module.exports = {
    'step one - start game': function(browser) {
        browser
            .url('http://new.femalesuperheroes.nl')
            .end();
    }
}
```

I'm using selenium server standalone 2.48.2 on Windows 8. The strange part is that using the same setup on a different machine running windows7 it runs just once, like it should.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Java version running on both of your machines. You probably have to update your Java version to the most recent version (1.8.0_65 should work fine).

See Nightwatch issue: https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/597

Comment: I wrote a NodeJs script using ShellJs to start  nightwatch test execution.I accidentally place the script under the test folder along with other tests.When nightwatch is started it executes all the tests in the tests folder.So I got an infinite loop of execution of tests as the nightwatch would be started again by the starting script accidentally placed in the test folder.Moving the starting script to a different folder,solved the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

when ever you want to go with the default environment dont use --env flag. it will run on the default settings itself. i think that may be the reason for your problem.

Comment: The purpose of an answer is to solve OP's problem. You shell not guess if it *can* help. Once you have enough reputation you can comment on questions, this would be a case where you could suggest this in a comment. **Not** as an answer though.